# Converting PromQL to SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, promql

I need to convert my prometheus metrics to pgsql using timescaleDB convertor,
I'm trying to change my queries from promQL to SQL. I had lots of queries and almost did them all but I stuck in this one and don't now can I convert this promQL query to SQL:

`sum(sum(increase(my_metric{}[1h])) by (label) > bool 0)`

My table is something like this: (ordered by label)

```
time(timestamptz), value(double), label(integer)
=================================================
2021-02-17 21:50:01.690092+00  3.1    1
2021-02-17 21:45:01.390661+00  4.1    1
2021-02-17 21:50:01.690092+00  4.5    2
2021-02-17 21:45:01.390661+00  4.5    2
2021-02-17 21:50:01.690092+00  1.23   3
2021-02-17 21:45:01.390661+00  4.46   3
```

What I need is  a counter that check value of each label during time, if the value is changed then it should add one to counter.
With promQL it's an easy task:
`sum(sum(increase(my_metric{}[5m])) by (label) > bool 0)`
or even:
`sum(max(increase(my_metric{}[5m])) by (label) > bool 0)`

For above data sample result should be 2 ,  it should add one for label 1 and 3, label 2 didn't change during that time so it should not add any to counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres you can use `lag()` and a cumulative count:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) filter (where prev_value is distinct from value) over (order by time) 
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by time) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t
```